# Exclude Groups from Pagination Count in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm having a slight issue with Tabulator.. Essentially, when creating a table, I want the table to display the number of rows currently shown (i.e. "Showing 1-10 of 13 total), this is easily achieved using the built in functions.

The issue is, when using groups, they are counted as rows, even though they hold no data.
If there is a table made with the page count as 10 (max of 10 rows per page) and there are 2 groups present, there would only be 8 rows of data, as the groups are counted in pagination.

My question is: is there a way or workaround to exclude groups from being counted in pagination...

Code pen for example:
https://codepen.io/lukeorriss/pen/dyZwwez?editors=1010

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug, you should raise a bug on the [Tabulator Git Repo](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Possible+Bug&template=bug_report.md&title=)